# Color overshoots when using \cellcolor without intercolumn space

Tags: tables, spacing, colortbl

When creating highly regular tables, I'm quite fond of the custom `C` column type shown below that accepts a width and centers the content, without having me worry about intercolumn space messing everything up.

Now when trying to color such a cell, strange things abound:

[image: Too much reeeed!]

How can I get rid of the spurious overshoot?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|C{2em}|C{2em}|}
\hline
a & \cellcolor{red}b \\\hline
c & d \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, you have to set the `colortbl` overhang of the column to `0pt` to match the `@{}` specification. As a side effect this will give all `C` cells an opaque white background:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{@{}>{\columncolor{white}[0pt]\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{}}
```

[image: Correct coloring]

Or in case you want to work with non-zero intercolumn space:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{@{\hspace{10pt}}>{\columncolor{white}[10pt]\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{\hspace{10pt}}}
```

[image: Coloring with spacing]

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `@{}` to avoid the separation space in the columntype (or additionally, if you want to keep it), you could use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` instead. This eliminates the color bleed. As this would be a global option you have to put the table in another environment to avoid side effects to other tables.

```
% from question
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{}}
\begin{tabular}{|C{2em}|C{2em}|}
\hline
a & {\cellcolor{red}}b \\ \hline
c & d \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

% implemented answer
{
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
  \newcolumntype{C}[1]{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{}}
  \begin{tabular}{|C{2em}|C{2em}|}
  \hline
  a & {\cellcolor{red}}b \\ \hline
  c & d \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
}
```

[image]

Comment: One should note, that `\tabcolsep` is now globally set to `0pt` -- it should be done inside another environment or within a `\begingroup...\endgroup` pair

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, thanks. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: But this only work if all columns are of type `C` (which is fair enough). Is there a way to change `\tabcolsep` only for `C` columns (other than using `\columncolor`)?

Comment: This works exact for me. Thanks!